# Is URL encoding sufficient for href attribute for protection against XSS?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

According to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.235_-_URL_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_URL_Parameter_Values), user input into an href attribute should "...except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters with ASCII values less than 256 with the %HH escaping format."

I don't understand the rationale behind this. Why can't URL encoding do the job? I have spent hours trying to create an attack vector for a URL string that is dynamically generated and presented back to the user, and to me, it seems like a pretty solid protection against XSS attacks.

I've also been looking into this for a while now and most people are advising to use URL encoding alongside HTML encoding. I totally get why HTML encoding is insufficient  because other vectors can still be utilised such as `onclick=alert()`

Can someone show me an example of an attack vector being used to manipulate an href which is being rendered with URL encoding and without HTML encoding or the encoding suggested by owasp.org in rule #5?

Answer (score 1):

No, if someone injects `javascript:alert(0)` then it will work. No method of encoding will prevent that, you should try to block javascript URI schemes along with all other URI schemes which would allow for XSS there, such as `data:` and `blob:` for example.

Recommended action is not to directly reflect user input into a link.

Additionally it is important to remember not to simply block these schemes precisely using something like `preg_replace` as line feeds would bypass this and produce an XSS payload. Such is: `java%0a%0dscript:alert(0);`. As you can see, a CRLF character was placed in the middle of the payload to prevent PHP (or other server-side languages) from recognizing it as `javascript:` which you have blocked. But HTML will still render this as `javascript:alert(0);` as the CRLF character is whitespace and ignored by HTML (within the value of an element's attribute), yet interpreted by PHP and other languages.

Comment: Do you have an example for the line feed bypass? Do you mean a page containing `<a href="java%0a%0dscript:alert(0);">Link</a>` will execute JavaScript when clicking the link? It's just treated as a relative http link when I try.

Comment: @cillian collins I can't seem to reproduce this I have the following:  <a href="javascript%3Aalert(document.cookie)">javascript:alert(document.cookie)</a> The %3 neutralises the XSS payload. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that the ':' is being percentage encoded is preventing the payload from working. If you're using a typical browser and sending the payload via a GET request, it will sometimes replace those kind of characters with percentage encoding, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: As for fgb, you are receiving the exact same issue. You are taking my payload literally, you don't paste the percentage encoded characters into the link, you instead paste them into a URL and then they will appear as a carriage return in the HTML. If you want to recreate it without having to create a vulnerable PHP application, just create a link and drop a return in the middle of the payload. You can alternatively use characters such as ``%09`` which should work in all browsers and even simply tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is context dependent. When you have a URL inside a HTML document, then you need both URL encoding and HTML encoding, but at different times.

> ...except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters with
>   ASCII values less than 256 with the %HH escaping format.

This is recommending to use URL encoding. But not for the whole URL. The context is when inserting URL parameters into the URL They need to be URL encoded just to allow for example `&` symbols in a value.

> Do not encode complete or relative URL's with URL encoding!

This is a separate rule for the whole URL Once the URL is encoded, then when inserting into a html attribute, then you apply html encoding.

You can't apply URL encoding to a complete URL, because it is already URL encoded and encoding it again will result in double encoding, corrupting the URL. For example, any `%` symbols in the original URL will be wrong.

HTML encoding is needed because of characters like ampersands are valid characters in URLs but have a different meaning in HTML because of character entities. It's possible for a URL to contain strings that look like HTML entities but aren't so need to be encoded when inserting into an HTML document.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the HTML encoding on top of URL encoding is not needed for security reasons but rather for proper presentation, am i understanding this correctly